# What is the motivation to decline C rule "a conditional expression does not yield an lvalue"?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, conditional-operator, lvalue

What is the motivation to decline C rule `a conditional expression does not yield an lvalue`?

In other words: in C it was a motivation (which exactly?) to `not yield an lvalue`. Why in C++ this motivation was declined (or reconsidered)?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I think they mean, why did C++ drop this rule that C has.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ has references; C does not.

You wouldn't be able to bind [mutable] references from an invocation of the conditional operator if not for the following rule:

> [`[expr.cond/5]`:](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond#5) If the second and third operands are glvalues of the same value category and have the same type, the result is of that type and value category and it is a bit-field if the second or the third operand is a bit-field, or if both are bit-fields.

Comment: Well, you could use `*(true ? &a : &b)` for non-bitfields.

Comment: @MSalters Indeed, but I'm guessing Bjarne felt that was needlessly hacky. Value categories got a bit of an overhaul anyway and I can't think of a particularly good reason that C did what it did beyond not having any reason at the time to complicate matters. Ultimately of course I'm only theorising; I was unable to find any rationale in the oldest design documents.

Answer (score 1):

An important reason (besides references) is that in C++, you can call member functions:

`(true ? a : b).foo();`. This will require a `this` pointer, which will be set to either `&a` or `&b`. In C, this is of course not possible.

Comment: You can invoke member functions on rvalues, so I don't see how this applies? Is that because every other example of such a use of an rvalue expression is preceded by a copy of some object or the creation of a new one? (Though I don't think that's necessarily inherent in that value category per se)